Click events doesn't work after add ssr to an angular 17 app
Click event doesn´t work after add @angular/ssr package, doesn´t show any log in the console.
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [RouterOutlet],
    template: `
  <button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
  <router-outlet />
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

    onClick(): void {
        console.log('Clicked');
    }
}

By the way, my app.config.ts:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        provideRouter(routes, withComponentInputBinding()),
        provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
        provideClientHydration(),
    ]
};

